Spring @Scheduled Ran Multiple Times
Sunday morning I was alerted that an application was sending too many emails. The service is on a cron schedule using the @Scheduled annotation and it ran at least 115 times that morning. It looks like it stopped when we hit the fallback on daylight savings time. I'm confused as to why this happened so many times
<parent>
   <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
   <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
   <version>2.6.4</version>
   <relativePath/>
</parent>

<spring-boot.version>2.7.5</spring-boot.version>
@Scheduled(cron = "0 0 0 * * *")
public void generateEligibilityFileReportForYesterday() {
    if(isMasterNode()) {
        LocalDate now = LocalDate.now();
        try {
            sendEmailForProcessedEligibilityFiles(now.minusDays(1), now.minusDays(1));
        } catch (IOException | EmailServiceException ex) {
            log.error("An exception occurred while sending processed eligibility files email", ex);
        }
    }
}

Logs showing multiple runs

Edit:
The cron did start running at midnight, it didn't start throwing errors until I stopped the email service around 1:30am. And it did repeatedly run this code but I don't know why.

We were able to reproduce the error. Created a small app that runs a few jobs. Set the clock to 11:59 pm Nov 2, when it ticked to midnight it started looping like crazy.

It would seem the problem was the version of spring

Just to ask an obvious question, but you don't happen to have this running in a cluster do you?  Perhaps isMasterNode() is returning true for all nodes in the cluster.

It is running in a cluster but it had never run on multiple nodes prior to this and we hadn't done a release in several weeks.

I would look at those log entries to see if they're from different nodes, if they are, investigate that, isMasterNode, method
